# Is there a simple way one can asynchronously execute a PHP code like in Node.JS?

Tags: php, asynchronous

Having worked on Node.JS for some projects, on receiving a request you can send a response to the user while executing other time-consuming code behind the scenes.

I have a PHP application using a customized framework for an API that returns JSON data.
I have a route for sending email when a user submits the recipient's email address and the mail message.

One is required to submit the required details. if the details are correct, the user should immediately receive a confirmation response, then start seeing an email based on the details they provided.

Is there any workaround since to immediately return a response to the user, I will be supposed to call the exit; function which will stop further code execution, and having in mind, sending an email will take about 10 seconds?

Comment: You should look into using Redis for dispatching jobs.

Comment: Can’t you just trigger this via an asynchronous AJAX request from the client side?

Comment: Or the API could just write the job to a queue which is then processed in the background by a scheduled cron job. Of course if your hosting provider doesn't allow cron then maybe think about going to a host which does.

Comment: @CBroe I cannot use AJAX since not all target clients may be supporting it. Upon submission, the client should immediately get feedback telling them the message has been submitted/queued then start processing the sending of the mail and never inform the client about the results, rather log failures on the server.

Comment: Which clients are you worried about? AJAX [is well supported accross all modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#browser_compatibility).

Comment: @NoahBoegli The real problem may not be about AJAX but speedy execution. The time the client waits when the email is being sent is what I want to eliminate and do it behind the client.

Comment: And how is AJAX not perfect for that? You fire off your AJAX request (it’s asynchronous, so further script execution _does not wait_ for a response at this point), and immediately after you show the user a message, “request has been sent.” When the actual response to the request arrives at the client some time later - you’re free to completely ignore it then (basically, making the AJAX request without any success/done handler), or you could at still check for errors at this point and inform the user, if something actually went wrong, if desirable.

Comment: @AlbertAlberto, You can create a new end point which has mailer functionality, and then make a curl request without waiting for response from your current function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any queuing system, like redis, amqp etc. Even though this is recommended there is some learning curve, and it's better to use it in conjunction with a PHP framework that already provides the appropriate transports.

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html as a Symfony example

However a simpler solution I have used before is a custom queue:

1. Create a table 'queue' with suggested fields [id, processed, email, date]
2. Save there the email information as a json string
3. Have a background job, like a cronjob in linux to running every few minutes, to actually send the emails.

Like this the user experience will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the subject "How can I execute a PHP code in background?", your hands are tied by your hosting provider.

Modern hosting providers allow for exec() and cron jobs. I suggest you look into an alternative hosting provider.